Krita: How to copy into an existing layer?
I am new to Krita 5.0.2 on my linux mint 22.
I have a gif and I want to edit it.
I already could paint in a single frame.
Now I wanted to copy another image into that frame.
Therefore I opened a new image in Krita, selected what I need and used Strg + C.
But when I copy it into my gif layer, a whole new layer is created.
But I want the chosen object to be put into my layer.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The easiest way is probably to just merge the layers. The shortcut is Ctrl+E.  This will merge the current layer with the layer below.
